# how to change the color of an mx:PieSeriesItem slice dynamically

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, adobe, charts, mxml

I am creating a program where a change in a value causes the color of a pie slice in an mx:PieChart to change dynamically.

the code that is supposed to change the color is similar to this:

```
(pieChart.pieChartSeries.items[i] as PieSeriesItem).fill  = new mx.graphics.SolidColor(0,0.2); // black, almost opaque
```

tracing out the results of this appears to apply the color to the particular PieSeriesItem, but the color does not change visually. I checked the AS reference and the fill property is of type iFill and should accept a solidColor instance. (note: I have also tried 0x000000 as a valid color, the first argument of SolidColor takes an uint)

Any thoughts on why the color would not be applied? comments appreciated.

[edit] Since I posted the question originally, I've added a few changes to help clarify the question.

1. I am actually using an MXML component that extends < mx:PieChart > . Originally I was trying to set the color as listed above within an event handler in the main application. What I have done since then was invoke a method in my extended PieChart component, like so:

(in main applicaion)

```
private function someEventHandler(evt:someEvent):void{
    pieChart.setPieSliceColor((pieChart.pieChartSeries.items[i] as PieSeriesItem));

}
```

1. In the custom pie Component, I have the following method defined:

   public setPieSliceColor(item:PieSeiesItem):void{
       item.fill = new mx.graphics.SolidColor(0x0000ff,1);
   this.invalidateSeriesStyles();

   }

now the change in color actually occurs, but is not seen until the user moves the  mouse **over** the respective pie slice! It's strange.

Any additional comments are appreciated.

thanks again

Edward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it...

something like this will work.

```
        public function setPieSliceColor(item:PieSeriesItem):void{
            item.fill = new mx.graphics.SolidColor(0x0000ff,1);
            this.setFocus();
            this.invalidateSeriesStyles();
                             // note this line
            item.currentState = "rollOver";
        }
```

It appears that although I was changing the color, the color would not effect until I actually mouseOver the slice...So setting the slice's (or item) currentState appears to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This seems correct, but I guess you'll need to redraw the control after you set this property. Have you tried calling the invalidateDisplayList and/or the invalidateProperties methods on the chart?

You could also use a fill function on the series to do this.

Comment: Hi Christophe - I actually added pieChart.invalidateDisplayList(); . Strange thing is that the color change only takes place _after_ I _MouseOver_ the actual pie slice! I need it to display more immediately. I thought of a fill function, but how would I can I call the function again? I thought it was only used when the pie was first rendered. I am going to make some edits to the question to add these details.

Comment: If you are extending the control, you might want to call the protected "invalidateData()" method when you change the fill. Regarding the fill function: this function is called again in "updateDisplayList()", so you should be able to invoke it by calling "invalidateDisplayList()".

Comment: Thanks Christophe for your feedback so far. I noticed that if I call invalidateData() the colors of the pieChart get reset  - which is not what I really want. I am going to try the filterfunction but a) does not that go through all the pie slices? I only want to update the specific slice, and b) at this moment I did not define an array of fills, I assume that I have to create one for the pieChart in order for it to know which "fill" in its fillArray to change?